# Javascript to detect and send a message to server if the window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, onbeforeunload

I want to know what the answer was for Window Close Confirmation to send a message to server regarding to window close!

I found this, but this doesn't return the user answer.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    var message = 'Are you sure?';
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
        }
    return message;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    var message = 'Are you sure?';
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
        if (evt.type == "unload" && evt.returnValue) {

            // ACTION WHICH SHOULD BE DONE ON CLOSE

        }
        evt.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the function returns, the window closes.

Whatever action you want to perform with `message` you'll have to do inside the onbeforeunload handler

Comment: I'd just like to chip in my experience with something like this: Performing actions like AJAX calls in beforeunload can wreck havoc on certain browsers, most notably Internet Explorer. I never found out why, we just reworked the application workflow to avoid these scenarios.